# M/M/1 queue with two types of customers, distribution of the total number of customers

Tags: stochastic-calculus, queueing-theory

I have problems to derive the following:

"A gas station offers two services. For each service customers arrive according to a Poisson process. On average 20 customers per hour for service 1 and 5 customers for service 2. The service times are exponential, both with a mean service time of two minutes.

Determine the distribution of the *total* number of customers in the system."

Using minutes as time units, I get $\rho_1=\lambda_1 \cdot \mathbb{E}[B]= \frac{1}{3} \cdot 2 = \frac{2}{3}$ and $\rho_2=\lambda_2 \cdot \mathbb{E}[B]= \frac{1}{12} \cdot 2 = \frac{1}{6}$.
So the distribution of the number of customers looking at the different services individually is
$$\mathbb{P}(L_1=n)=(1-\rho_1)(\rho_1)^n=\frac{1}{3}\Big(\frac{2}{3}\Big)^n$$
and 
$$\mathbb{P}(L_2=n)=(1-\rho_2)(\rho_2)^n=\frac{5}{6}\Big(\frac{1}{6}\Big)^n .$$

For the distibution of the total number of customers, I thought about
$$\mathbb{P}(L=n)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\mathbb{P}(L_1=k,L_2=n-k).$$

From there, I do not really know how to compute is further. Am I on the right track? Does anybody has a hint how to compute it?

Comment: How do you conclude "So the distribution of the number of customers of each type is..." ?  That is not a correct application of M/M/1 results.  If you have Poisson arrivals of rate $\lambda$ and jobs have independent and i.i.d. exponential service times, then you can apply the formula for an $M/M/1$ queue.  You cannot  individually apply the M/M/1 formula on some of the packets but ignore the fact that there are other packets from another process that also affect the queue.  In this case, you want to use the fact that the superposition of two independent Poisson processes is again Poisson.

Comment: Another way to see this is: If only type 1 customers existed, their mass function would be $(1/3)(2/3)^n$.  Now if type 2 customers are present, then that changes things, so wouldn't you expect the distribution of type 1 customers to change?

Comment: I think my reproducing og the task was not correct enough, I will edit that. In the task the two types of customers seek different services, each service has a mean service time of 2 minutes. Hence my answer for the distribution of the number of customers for each type.

Comment: In that case there are indeed two independent M/M/1 queues, rather than a single queue with two types of customers.  So your discrete convolution is correct, you need to use "independence" of $L_1$ and $L_2$  to claim that $$P[L_1=k, L_2=n-k]=P[L_1=k]P[L_2=n-k]$$

Comment: It is unclear here whether customers of type $1$ are in the same queue or a different queue as customers of type $2$.